# Which tool to check wether WCF tcp transport is really encrypted

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding, packet-sniffers

I want to convince myself, that the default setting with NetTcpBinding is Transport thus my sent data is encrypted and not in clear text.

Which tool would you recommend to check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wireshark! http://www.wireshark.org/ (It works, it's free (& it's the only one I could remember the name of))